# Facebook like error in the app id or admin id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

The FB debug tool gave this error while i tried for FB like button, it was working on my local server but after making site live this error occurs. The exact text shown by FB debug is given below.

of type 'product' is invalid because the given value '62120958532' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

and the URL of my site is http://www.ashton-blakey-antiques.com .

Answer (score 0):

I received this error. Simply remove the admin tag as it isn't needed especially since your passing the app id!

Having had a quick look the homepage source code there isnt an admin tag present and that works. Give it a try

Hope this helps

Comment: I did wat u sad.it helped but now the debug tool is showing error of circular redirect path..with response code 200..and showing exact image that i want but its not showing the same image on FB like.

Comment: have you looked at the domain name in the facebook developer portal. I did a lint on a product page and got the following

"invalid because the domain 'www.ashton-blakey-antiques.com' is not allowed for the specified application"

Answer (score 0):

You specified page id instead of user id for `fb:admins` property.

`fb:app_id` property is for application id